# Editing a Textfile in Python

Tags: python, text-files

I have a textfile on my desktop called 'TEXTFILE.docx', in the text file it reads 'Hello my name is Jimmy Jones'. I basically want to call this text file up into python so i can apply some functions that i have made (One that removes vowels and replaces it with blank spaces - and another one that doubles each character [i.e input = the, returns = tthhee])

```
def withoutVowels(string):
    for vowel in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]:
        string = string.replace(vowel, " ")
    return string
```

Above is the function that removes vowels and replaces it with empty spaces.

```
def doubleChar(doubleit):
    doubled = []
    for letter in doubleit:
        doubled.append(letter*2)
    return "".join(doubled)
```

Above is my function that doubles the letter

```
textfile = open('TEXTFILE.docx', 'w')
```

Above is how i have attempted to open the textfile.

I then tried printing the textfile and this came up:
*<_io.TextIOWrapper name='TEXTFILE.docx' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>*
Is it possible to assign whatever is in the TEXTFILE to a variable??

Also, i thought perhaps the problem i was having is because python can't call up "Word Document Files" but i looked for a program that used .txt files but i couldn't fund a program on my mac that would use .txt files.

Comment: docx files are not plain text. Have a look at https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you actually *don't* have a text file, you have a Microsoft Word file. You need to open the file in Word and chose File->Save As..., and save it as a "Plain Text" file.

Answer (score 1):

When you're opening the textfile, what are your overall intentions? Do you intend to just read the file? Or do you want to both read the file and change it?  If you're just reading, open the file with:

```
textfile = open("textfile.txt","r") #instead of "w," use "r" for reading. "r+" is both.
#Then, go on to read the string
text = str(textfile.read()) #str() is not necessary, but it can't hurt
#Now, the variable "text" is a big string - it contains whatever was in that text file. 
#Then, you can apply your function to it. 
print withoutVowels(text)
print doubleChar(text)
```

EDIT: The above answer is also correct - you have to copy and paste everything from the Word file into a .txt file (something like Notepad) for the program to work.

Comment: i want to use the text in the textfile to make another text file, where both my functions are applied

Comment: To do that, you can read up on Python File I/O. It's pretty simple, and that's coming from a beginner programmer. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm You'll have to take the code above and add to the end a bit to make it do what you want. Don't be afraid to play around and don't be afraid to make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you want to do is this:

```
textfile.read()
```

You see, the `textfile` is a "file-like" object that supports a bunch of interesting methods. Read up more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Comment: will not help as he is trying to read a docx file not a txt file as the title suggests

Comment: it does answer his question, though: how to view the contents of a file object.

Comment: hmmm, if he wants to read lots of hex then i guess it does help :>>> textfile = open('not_a_textfile.docx')
>>> t_read = textfile.read()
>>> t_read
'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x89\x01\xa4\x1b\xfc

Comment: I guess *ex falso quodlibet* applies: The question has some serious mistakes in it (like, the title, the question and the probable intent not being congruent) and that is where our difference is arrising. Turns out, the docx seems to be a zip file with a bunch of xml files inside. So you "could" write your own reader, which might even work for special cases. But you are 100% right: This is not the solution to his underlying problem. Then again: Still useful to know some basic python - makes asking well formed questions easier ;-)

Comment: you are write also, i was just in a bad mood yesterday, :-)

Comment: :-) glad to hear you're feeling better today!

Comment: @DarenThomas Could u please also help me with my problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64914906/searching-backwards-trough-a-text-file-adding-new-line-after-specific-string?noredirect=1#comment114768522_64914906